# how to communicate between independent components in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, events, components, communication

I have 2 components

1: modal component
2: table component

when we add a data in modal component api call is made and i will get the response on success need to refresh table which no where related to modal

after reading few article came to know i can use event bus

please point some right same reference or good approach to achieve